# Resizing BufferedImage

Tags: swing

i would like to resize a BufferedImage that is draw using the Graphics drawing method with AffineTransform object.

```
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.scale(1, -1);
        at.translate((int) xPos - xIncr, -(int)yPos);
        ((Graphics2D) g).drawImage(line, at, null);
```

How could i resize the image, that is smaller than the area i want it to be draw in ?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're already drawing the image with an `AffineTransform`, why not just apply another `scale` to expand your image by the desired amount?

```java
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.scale(1, -1);
at.scale(2.5, 3.0); // replace these with more appropriate scale factors
at.translate((int) xPos - xIncr, -(int)yPos);
((Graphics2D) g).drawImage(line, at, null);
```

Comment: Allright, thank you i wanted to avoid having to calculate the scale factor, but i guess there is no choice.  Thank you.